# Coupon collector's problem worst case time?

Tags: probability

The expected time is $n Hn$. So for 9 coupons we get ~26 trials. But what is the probability that all coupons have been collected after 26 trials? How do we know the number of trials required to collect all with arbitrary certainty?

---

```
(* Wolfram Mathematica: *)

(*Exact, but slow for n > 200*)
trialsToP2[c_,n_,k_] := (n!/((n-c)! n^k)) StirlingS2[k,n]

(*Approximate*)
trialsToP[n_,t_] := Block[{u,p},
  u = (t-n Log[n])/n;
  p = Exp[-Exp[-u]];
  p
  ]

trialsFromP[n_,p_] := Block[{u,t},
  u = Log[1/Log[1/p]];
  t = n * Log[n] + n *u;
  t
  ]
```

---

The results seem pretty close even for small values of N:

```
Input          | Results
N   P          | trialsFromP trialsToP2 trialsToP
9   EulerGamma | 25.16       0.5904     0.5772
    0.99       | 61.1764     0.9932     0.99
               |
100 EulerGamma | 520.4       0.5790     0.5772
    0.99       | 920.532     0.9905     0.99


a = test[9, EulerGamma] 
b = test[9, 0.99]
c = test[100, EulerGamma]
d = test[100, 0.99]

test[n_, p_] := Block[{t,p1,p2},
  t  = trialsFromP[n, p];
  p1 = trialsToP2[n, n, Round[t]];
  p2 = trialsToP[n, t];

  {N[t, 4], N[p1, 4], N[p2, 4]}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T_n$ denote the time needed to complete all $n$ coupons. Then $T_n/(n\log n)\to1$ almost surely when $n\to\infty$, in particular, $P[T_n\gt (1+x)n\log n]\to0$ and $P[T_n\lt(1-x)n\log n]\to0$ when $n\to\infty$, for every positive $x$.

To refine this, note that $P[T_n\lt n\log n+nu]\to\mathrm e^{-\mathrm e^{-u}}$ for every real number $u$. 
In other words, $T_n=n\log n+nU_n$ where $U_n\to U$ in distribution and the density $f_U$ of $U$ is such that $f_U(u)=\mathrm e^{-u-\mathrm e^{-u}}$ for every real number $u$.

If $n=9$, then $n\log n+nu=26$ for $u=.692$ and $\exp(-\mathrm e^{-.692})\approx.606$. This suggests that for 9 coupons, all coupons are collected at or before the 26th trial with probability roughly 60%. Assuming 9 is large enough for the asymptotics to be relevant...

Comment: Is it correct to assume 26^(0.99*e) gives all 9 with a 99% chance?

Comment: Since 26^(0.99*e) is roughly 6400, probably much more than 99%. Why 26^(0.99*e)?

Comment: Was just guessing at how it scales, since both 26*(0.37*E) == 26 and 26^(0.37*E) == 26, and 26*E==70 seemed too low to have a 100% chance.

Comment: Nevermind, i guess its 26*Log[1/Log[1/p]], p = 0.99.

But what is the correct way to calculate the base expected time. $nHn$ gives 25.46 but $n Log n$ gives 19.7.

Comment: @Neal: $25.46$ is the expected time (rounded).

Comment: @Did: Your probability looks too low: in particular, since this is right skewed, I would think the mean should be more than the median so the probability of being below the mean should be over $\frac12$.

Comment: @Henry What is right skewed?

Comment: @Did: the distribution of the number of coupons required to be purchased to get a full set: with $9$ types of coupons the skewness seems to be about $+0.4$.

Comment: @Did: The mean is $nH_n$ not $n\log_e n$ so with $n=9$ about $25.46$ rather than about $19.775$, and this is always be an important difference. Your approximation of $\frac{1}{\mathrm e}$ then fails because you are applying $P[T_n\lt n\log n+nu]\to\mathrm e^{-\mathrm e^{-u}}$ when $u=0$ when you should be applying it when $u=\gamma \approx 0.5772156649$. This would give you $P[T_n\lt n H_n]\to P[U\lt \gamma ]=\exp(-\exp(-\gamma)) \approx 0.570376$. This is much more plausible as the right skewness suggest a figure greater than $\frac12$.

Comment: Empirically $0.57$ is a better estimate: the probability of having a full set of $9$ types from $25$ or fewer attempts is about $0.590$ and from $26$ or fewer attempts is about $0.629$.  As another example, with $100$ types of coupons, the expected number required is about $518.73775$: the probabilit of $518$ or fewer is about $0.5725$ and of $519$ or fewer is about $0.5757$.

Comment: See edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: @Henry: Excuse my ignorance, but does the value of U describe the amount of standard deviations offset from the median?

Comment: @Neal - no, as I think the median is $23$ and the standard deviation is just under $10$ when $n=9$.  $nU_n$ is the difference between the number of trials required and $n\log_e n$.  But you should really ask this of Did; my answer takes a different approach.

Answer (score 7):

If there are $n$ types of coupons, and you sample $k$ times with replacement, the probability you have $C=c$ different coupons has the recursion

$$\Pr(C=c|n,k)=\frac{n-c+1}{n}\Pr(C=c-1|n,k-1) + \frac{c}{n}\Pr(C=c|n,k-1)$$

starting at $\Pr(C=0|n,0)=1$ and $\Pr(C=c|n,0)=0$ for $c \ne 0$.

You can do the calculation for example on a spreadsheet to find $\Pr(C=9|n=9,k=26) \approx 0.62912$.

More precisely, this is $\dfrac{9!}{9^{26}}S_2(26,9)$ where  $S_2(r,n)$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and in general   $$\Pr(C=c|n,k) =  \dfrac{n!}{(n-c)!n^{k}} S_2(k,c).$$

To have $99\%$ certainty with $9$ types of coupons, you need to sample up to $58$ times;  $99.9\%$ certainty requires $78$.